# Automating Web of Knowledge H-index output

Tags: javascript, mysql, html

I'm a research student looking to compare the H-indexes (a measure of how often a scientist's work has been cited by others) of a comma-separated list of people.  Web of Knowledge has a javascript form that lets you enter the author's name (field) and their institution (radio button).  The h-index is then given as html.  How would I go about automating the search and culling out the h-index value for each researcher?

Comment: What's "Web of Knowledge"?  Where is this "javascript form"?

Answer (score 0):

One fairly simple way would be to write a script that uses [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to simulate a submission of the form over the data set you want to use.  You'll need to know the form type (POST or GET) and what the parameter names are, then you can fill them out, feeding in data from the command line, a file, or a constant to your script.

The only trick here appears to be that Web of Knowledge will require you to authenticate to use this form.